# $HOME vs ~ for use in bash scripts

Tags: bash

$HOME vs ~ for use in bash scripts

I want to make my code more consistent.  Should I use

```
export export_location=~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
export path_bash="$HOME/root/config/bash/"
```

Both appear to work fine, but which is best so I can make my code base consistent

Comment: IMO, consider the `~` a shortcut for the interactive shell; use `$HOME` as both more readable and less error-prone in a script.

Answer (score 15):

`~` has no special meaning within a string, it's just a squiggly character:

```
$ echo ~
/home/marc
$ echo "~"
~
```

That's where `$HOME` comes in, which CAN be used within a string and get expanded out to the user's home directory

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/marc
$ echo "$HOME"
/home/marc
```

Comment: But tilde expansion happens in assignments, too, cf. `x=~ ; echo "$x"` and `x='~'; echo "$x"`.

Comment: yes, but if the tilde is inside quotes, then it's not "insert home directory here", it's just a squiggle.

Comment: The OP isn't quoting the tilde; this doesn't really provide an answer to the question of which to use.

Comment: @chepner: sure it does. it explains why it's `foo="$HOME"` v.s. `foo=~/...`

Comment: He's not asking why one is quoted and the other isn't; he simply asking which to use.

Comment: and I show what the difference between the two is... "which pill should I take" "this one kills you, this one makes you better" - if you can't figure out an appropriate answer from that on you own, spelling it out won't help either.

Comment: "Both appear to work fine, but which is best ...". You are the only one talking about the difference between quoted and unquoted tildes.

Answer (score 11):

Tilde `~` is replaced by the contents of `$HOME`, but only when it is unquoted.

Your examples are apples and oranges, what you *should* compare is:

```
export path_bash="~/root/config/bash/"
export path_bash="$HOME/root/config/bash/"
```

Now they are similar and can be compared.  The first one will not be expanded.  This is an issue if you need other expansion which requires quotes, like another variable or whitespace.

As a general principle code should be easy to read, and `$HOME` is more obvious than a `~`, although that is subjective.

Comment: also ~ can be used like ( cd ~${user}/ ) to go a specific user $HOME directory

Comment: @nabeel: also ~ can be used on the directory stack as `~n`, but the OP is not using it like that either.

Comment: @nabeel No, it can't. Tilde expansion happens prior to parameter expansion.

Comment: @nabeel: `cd ~${user}`  attempts to `cd` to a directory name beginning with a literal `~` character (which is legal, if unwise).

Answer (score 2):

I normally prefer `$HOME` over `~` in scripts, because then I don't have to worry about whether pathname expansion works in a given context. Sometimes it doesn't work and then `$HOME` is a must and if you worry about consistency then it's best to stick with `$HOME` even for cases where it's equivalent to `~`.

Here is a simple example:

```
$ echo java -classpath ~/dir1:~/dir2 ...
java -classpath /home/david/dir1:~/dir2 ...
```

As you can see, the first part of the `classpath` argument was expanded fine, but not the second part, since it was not recognized as a separate path by the shell. But using `java -classpath ~/dir1:$HOME/dir2 ...` would look weird. So `java -classpath "$HOME/dir1:$HOME/dir2" ...` is the least confusing solution.

Some programs will recognize `~` in pathnames and will expand it themselves, so in some context it appears to be working, even though the shell didn't do the expansion, in other cases it will break. Sticking to `$HOME` will avoid all these confusions.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to obscure the main point of my previous answer, but for the sake of completeness I'd like to point out that there *is* a technical difference between `~` and `$HOME` which can be shown with two lines:

```bash
$ env -u HOME bash -c 'echo ~'
/home/david
$ HOME=anything bash -c 'echo ~'
anything
```

So in case `HOME` is unset (not just empty) bash will expand `~` to the home directory of the user specified in `/etc/passwd`, otherwise it will expand to whatever the value of `$HOME` is.

But an unset `HOME` is surely an edge case and in this case all kinds of stuff would break, so the first thing you'd do in such an environment would probably be something like:

```bash
export HOME=~
```

Also, this behavior is bash specific. Other shells won't handle this gracefully:

```bash
$ for shell in /bin/{,ba,c,tc,da,fi,k,z}sh; do printf "%s:\t" $shell; env -u HOME $shell -c 'echo ~'; done
/bin/sh:    ~
/bin/bash:  /home/david
/bin/csh:
/bin/tcsh:  No $home variable set.
/bin/dash:  ~
/bin/fish:  /home/david
/bin/ksh:   /home/david
/bin/zsh:   /home/david
```

As you can see, `tcsh` throws an error when trying to expand `~` with an unset `HOME`. `csh` would expand to an empty string, and `dash` leaves a literal `~`. `sh` here is linked to `dash` so exhibits the same behavior. On other systems like macOS it's linked to `bash` and behaves accordingly there. Also, `csh` on macOS is hardlinked to `tcsh` and behaves accordingly. And `ksh` on macOS seems to be a very old version which expands to the username instead of the home directory.

So no, don't rely on `~` doing more than `$HOME`.